# Peek of multiprocessing.queue?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have multiple worker processes reading from the same `multiprocessing.queue()`. Each worker process only read contents belongs to itself, and must leave the other contents untouched. So basically the worker process must first check the queue contents then decides whether to pop one item.

Is there any way to do this with `multiprocessing.queue`?

Comment: Maybe you need to write a dispatcher instead.

Comment: @PeterWood Yeah, if I have to use multiple queues, a dispatcher will be necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can always put back messages that you don't need (**if order is not an issue**)

```
def get_my_job():

    while True:
        job = q.get()
        if job == 'mine':
            return job
        q.put(job)
        time.sleep(random()/2) #preventing deadlocks...
```

If the order is important you may use multiple Queues for so each message **type** will be in its own Queue

```
queues = { 'queue4worker_type1': Queue(),
           'queue4worker_type2': Queue(),
          }
#each worker can now consume only messages for its wanted types ...
```

Comment: Doesn't this change the order of processing by the other processes? The code shown will spin if there is no my_job, right?

Comment: As I stated above, this does change the order of processing ... I'll add another option if the order is important ...

Comment: Will this be less efficient? I mean by first removing then putting it back?

Comment: @Jedi - Yes it will, But if each item take enough time to process it won't be noticeable ...

Comment: Since there's no other answer for quite a time, I'll pick this answer as final

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can peek by emptying the queue onto another queue and returning the duplicated queue.

```
import multiprocessing

def peek(queue):    
    queue_ = multiprocessing.Queue()

    # do the peek
    peeked = queue.get()
    
    # copy the original queue
    queue_.put(peeked)
    while not queue.empty():
        queue_.put(queue.get())

    return queue_, peeked

queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
queue.put("A")
queue.put("B")
queue.put("C")

queue, peeked = peek(queue)

print(peeked)
print(queue.get())
```